# What is the space-time medium?

Tags: forces, spacetime, aether

1. What is the space-time medium?
2. According to [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/5581/56606): "... fields are a fundamental part of the universe." Then why do we describe a gravity as being depressions in space-time?
3. And why don't we describe weak, strong, or electromagnetic forces as such?
4. Have we actually proved that there is no substance that makes space-time?
5. Also is there a difference between the ideas of aether and [quantum foam](http://ldolphin.org/qfoam.html)?

Comment: There are too many questions here, but each of them is either a duplicate or doesn't really make sense: For "describing electromagnetic forces as such", see [Geometric interpretation of Electromagnetism](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76354/50583). What does "describing a gravitational field as propagating through some space-time sheet" mean? What would it mean to "prove" (or disprove) that there is a "substance that makes space-time"? What exactly are you referring to when you say "quantum foam"?